# Select or update only one duplicate from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, count, duplicates, common-table-expression

What I want to do is to set column `Deleted` = 1 for all duplicates in table `Customers` except of one. So that one entry remains.

Table:

```
| Deleted | ID   | Number | Name  |
-----------------------------------
| 0       | 2A3E | 100004 | Andy  | 
| 0       | 9P3W | 102506 | Judy  |
| 0       | 3R4Z | 120097 | Freddy| 
| 0       | 1G5Y | 103905 | Nikky |
| 0       | 2A3E | 103905 | Nikky | 
| 0       | 9P3W | 147001 | Johnny|
| 0       | 5K7V | 120097 | Teddy | 
| 0       | 6D8S | 120097 | Teddy |
```

Query:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Number) count_calc
    FROM Customers
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE count_calc > 1
```

Results:

```
| Deleted | ID   | Number | Name  |
-----------------------------------
| 0       | 1G5Y | 103905 | Nikky |
| 0       | 2A3E | 103905 | Nikky | 
| 0       | 5K7V | 120097 | Teddy | 
| 0       | 6D8S | 120097 | Teddy |
```

Now I want set `Deleted` = 1 for only one Nikky and one Teddy.

Tried `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but didn't work. How can I modify the query so that it returns only one of these duplicates from Nikky and Teddy and not both? But at the same time returns all columns so that I can set `Deleted` of one to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are part-way there, you need to use `row_number` over a window, then you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with d as (
    select * , Row_Number() over(partition by number order by id) rn
    from customers
)
update d set deleted=1 where rn>1
```